# Python exe crashes after arithmetic operation

Tags: python

I wrote some code to create a basic calculator in python. I converted it to .exe using pyinstaller.
it works fine till the operation part. whenever I try to do an operation the program just crashes.
heres the code:

```
print("1 is for addition")
print("2 is for subtraction")
print("3 is for multiplication")
print("4 is for getting the quotient of an opration(division)")
print("5 is for getting the remainder of an opration")


a=int(input("Welcome. enter an opration to continue."))
if a==1:
    f=int(input("Enter first number :"))
    s=int(input("Enter second number :"))
    print("Your answer is : ",f+s)  
elif a==2:
    f=int(input("Enter first number :"))
    s=int(input("Enter second number :"))
    print("Your answer is : ",f-s)
elif a==3:
    f=int(input("Enter first number :"))
    s=int(input("Enter second number :"))
    print("Your answer is : ",f*s)
elif a==4:
    f=int(input("Enter first number :"))
    s=int(input("Enter second number :"))
    print("Your answer is : ",f/s)
elif a==5:
    f=int(input("Enter first number :"))
    s=int(input("Enter second number :"))
    print("Your answer is : ",f%s)
else:
    print("Error: invalid choice.Please choose a valid integer between 1 and 5")
```

Comment: I'd like to see a preview of the video without downloading any files to my computer

Comment: Sounds like after the operation the program is done and it exits right away, not a crash.

Comment: How do you know it crashes? Edit the question. See [ask] and how to create a [mcve]. Also, please don't post pictures of text or videos.

Comment: f and s are there f=int(input("Enter first number :")) s=int(input("Enter second number :"))

Comment: I dont think it crashes just the program exits

Comment: What is the issue then? Programs exit when they're completed.

Comment: That's not crashing. That's your command window closing before you can see the result. Do you run it through command line? If not, just add a `time.sleep()` at the end.

Comment: ok lemme try ...

Answer (score 0):

IN the python Shell window you can see the answer because the window doesn't close after it is done but when you compile it to (.exe) or open it in the console it will just close.
In order to prevent this just add

```
input()
```

at the end and it will show on the screen until you press ENTER key.

> ***or*** you can put
> `import time` at the beginning and `time.sleep(5)` at the end to show the output for 5 sec you can change the 5